# ASP.Net WebForm c# WebService - The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, webforms

I'm using ASP.Net WebForm & a C# Web Service and am getting the below error when running my code;

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. 
The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

I've tried putting the below into the web config but it's not resolved it;

```
<system.web.extensions>
 <scripting>
  <webServices>
   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
  </webServices>
 </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

My Web Service;

```
        public class OpenRequisitions
    {
        public string string1 { get; set; }
        public string sstring2 { get; set; }
        public string string3 { get; set; }
        public string string4 { get; set; }
        public string string5 { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<OpenRequisitions> GetOpenReqData(string ReqId, string RequisitionTitle, string City, string Country, string DateCreated)
    { 
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONN"].ConnectionString;
        string commandTextGetOpenRequisitions = Properties.Queries.commandTextGetOpenRequisitions;
        List<OpenRequisitions> GetOpenRequisitionData = new List<OpenRequisitions>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandTextGetOpenRequisitions, con);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                OpenRequisitions results = new OpenRequisitions();
                results.ReqId = rdr["string1"].ToString();
                results.RequisitionTitle = rdr["string2"].ToString();
                results.City = rdr["string3"].ToString();
                results.Country = rdr["string4"].ToString();
                results.DateCreated = rdr["string5"].ToString();

                GetOpenRequisitionData.Add(results);
            }
        }
        return GetOpenRequisitionData;
    }
```

Comment: I saw an old article that said setting `maxJsonLength` to more than `999999999` made the site/service go belly-up. Try reducing the size. Do you know how much is actually being returned?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to JavaScriptSerializer. You can set a max value on that directly. It doesn't inherit the value from web.config.

```
// Create an instance of your JavaScriptSerializer and set the MaxJsonLength.
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090 };

// Perform your serialization
serializer.Serialize("Your JSON Contents");
```

[Source](http://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/)